# Does this have overlapping subproblems?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, math, dynamic-programming, recurrence

Let's say that I have a sequence defined as:
f[n] = 2*f[n-1]+1

With f[0] = 0 and f[1] = 1.

I would like to find the nth element in this sequence using a program (recursion). Does it have overlapping subproblems?

Maybe yes, because the same subproblem of f[n-1] is technically "used" more than once in the construction of the solution to f[n]...

Or maybe no, because in reality, the recursive function never solves the same problem twice... and runs in O(n)...?

Does this problem have overlapping subproblems or not?

Comment: It doesn't have overlapping subproblems. It does have a trivial closed-form solution, which is `f[n] = 2**n - 1`.

Comment: Wait but what if I write f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-1] + 1. Doesn't this give overlapping subproblems (say, if I implement this using a recursive algorithm)?

Comment: You seem to have a solution that's looking for a problem. Just google "dynamic programming" to find some real problems with real subproblems.

Answer (score 1):

No, here recursion goes linearly level by level, no branching (as in Fibonacci recursive solution), so any f[k] is calculated once.

Note that there is no need in recursion - simple for-loop looks fine and more clear.

Comment: if I write f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-1] + 1. Doesn't this give overlapping subproblems (say, if I implement this using a recursive algorithm)?

Comment: You artificially introduce repeating subproblems - but why? Problem itself requires the only previous result to calculate current value.

Comment: Ok so you're saying even though I **can** artificially introduce repeating ("overlapping") subproblems, the problem still doesn't have overlapping subproblems by definition.

Comment: I don't understand your  goals. Some complex problems might be solved if we can represent them through overlapping subproblems, so reusing solution helps to solve faster. This problem by it's nature requires linear step-by-step calculation, so yes, we can say `doesn't have overlapping subproblems by definition. `